# Is there more than 1 type of light novel in the Spice and Wolf series?

Tags: spice-and-wolf, light-novel-production

I've always thought there is only 1 type of light novel for this series (which is translated to other languages).
But I saw on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0759531048) that they are offering to sell 3 types of the same light novel.

You can see that below the title section, where it says "See all 3 formats and editions". After that, you need to press the arrow on the left side to see all the 3 novels.

I'm wondering what are the differences between them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are just the different cover release versions. At one point, Yen Press was printing these with a slipcover case on them that shows a more "appealing cover" for the Americanized audience. However, not everyone liked this. They're not available anymore and were a limited print only, so the versions Amazon has listed are the normal and slip covered version (plus the one they fulfill, the none slip cover one.)

[You can find the original press release here.](http://www.yenpress.com/2009/11/spice-and-wolf-the-solution/)

I actually own some of these, although I usually display the original Japanese covers as I prefer them. I've attached some photos so you can get a good idea of how they look in real life.

I hope this helps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much
Honestly, as long as it is basically the same, I prefer the cartoonish style. it's given me more original filing.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju The content is identical.

Comment: yeah, that's what I've understood from your answer.
much appreciate =]